# sql select with no duplicates in both columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I want to select rows without duplicate values in columns. What I mean is that if there is a row with | 2 | 1 | and another one with | 1 | 2 | in the current selection, I want to show only one of them.

```
+------+------+
| id1  | id2  |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    4 |    3 |
|    3 |    4 |
|    1 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

so in the example above it will select only first, last and either second OR third row.

and also to substitute these values with the string 'TITLE' from another table.

table values:

```
 +----+----------+
 | id | title    |
 +----+----------+
 |  1 | title1   |
 |  2 | title2   |
 |  3 | title3   |
 |  4 | title4   |
 +----+----------+
```

so that the final select would have only titles in rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `least` and `greatest` to do this. `least` gets the lower value of id1,id2 and `greatest` gets the greater of id1,id2.

```
select distinct least(id1,id2),greatest(id1,id2)
from t
```

Actually the above generates rows which aren't in the table. To avoid it, you need a `left join` with a derived table.

```
select t1.id1,t1.id2 
from t t1
left join (select least(id1,id2) as id1,greatest(id1,id2) as id2
           from t
           group by least(id1,id2),greatest(id1,id2)
           having count(*) > 1
          ) t2 on t2.id1=t1.id1 and t2.id2=t1.id2
where t2.id1 is null and t2.id2 is null
```

Edit: To get the title strings from a different table based on id's

```
select t1.id1,t1.id2,tt1.title,tt2.title 
from t t1
left join (select least(id1,id2) as id1,greatest(id1,id2) as id2
           from t
           group by least(id1,id2),greatest(id1,id2)
           having count(*) > 1
          ) t2 on t2.id1=t1.id1 and t2.id2=t1.id2
join titles tt1 on tt1.id=t1.id1 --use a left join if the titles table won't have all the id's
join titles tt2 on tt2.id=t1.id2 --use a left join if the titles table won't have all the id's
where t2.id1 is null and t2.id2 is null
```

Comment: Wow, it really helped. Can you also help with substitution of the current values in this table with the values that stored in another table? If I have table 'values' with the string values for each id, how do I have only the strings got printed (selected)?

Comment: I have another table 'values' with two columns:  'id' and string 'Title'. I need to substitute the ids of the select in OP post with the 'titles'. I hope I made it clearer

Comment: no, show some sample data from the table, like the one in question. please edit your question to reflect it.

Comment: thanks for the help...but I can't make it work the way you wrote it. The first one with 'distinct' works well and doesn't generate any new rows. The examples below it are not working properly...

Comment: made it work kind of. With DISTINCT (it really does work normally I think) and Joins. Seems to be working. Thanks for the help, man